# Can I rebind EOF in bash/Readline?

Tags: bash, readline

I'd like to unbind C-d from sending EOF in bash, and set it to another key.  The idea is to keep C-d as EOF in my `.bashrc`, but to rebind it in my `.bash_profile`, so that hitting C-d repeatedly with pull me out of any subshells I'm in, but leave me in my login shell.

Is this possible?  C-d seems to be bound to `delete-char`, which it performs if there's text on the current line.  It only sends EOF if there's no text on the current line.  Rebinding `delete-char` to, say, C-f applies the `delete-char` action, but not the EOF sending.

Does Readline offer a way to rebind the EOF command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you're talking about is set by `stty`. Why don't you bind another keystroke to either emit C-d or nothing depending on whether you're in a login shell or a non-login shell and use *that*?

Answer (score 2):

No, but `stty eof` will allow you to change the EOF character. And it's a really bad idea to do so.

Comment: Why is changing the EOF character bad?  I believe you, I'd just like to understand it.

Comment: Too many things in the unix realm depend on EOF and if you train your fingers to behave differently, it will likely bite you in a situation you didn't expect and if you should ever sit down at keyboard with a standard binding, you'd be unhappy. My answer now sounds more dire than was intended , substitute "can I bind CAPS LOCK to generate SPACE" and my answer is the same.